# Two tables side by side with independent and global captions

Tags: tables, subfloats, two-column, subcaption

I want to put two tables side by side in my document, with (a) and (b) subcaptions for them, and also a global caption "Table 1. Blahblahblah" (spanning to one of the columns only). At the moment I am only able to put the tables with independent captions (as seen in the image below). I've tried the subcaption package and subtable but it claims that subtable environment was undefined. I've also tried the subfigure package but it clashes with the subfig package.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\thispagestyle{plain}   % To force page numbering when using conference IEEEtran
\pagestyle{plain}   % To force page numbering when using conference IEEEtran
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}  % For autoref to name subfloats as Figure
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}

%%%%%%%%%% FIGURES %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}   % Figures caption
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup{labelsep = period}  % Figure 2. Caption (rather than Figure 2: Caption)
\usepackage{float}  % To place figures where I want with [H]
\usepackage{subfig} % For subfigures
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}  % Fig.2 (rather than Figure 2)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}        
\begin{table}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{subfloat}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                    30 & 0.75 \\ \hline
                    50 & 1.25 \\ \hline
                    70 & 1.75 \\ \hline
                    100 & 2.50 \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the FFT algorithm at different heights}
                \label{tab:dimFFT}
            \end{subfloat}%
            \begin{subfloat}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                    30 & 0.28 \\ \hline
                    50 & 0.47 \\ \hline
                    70 & 0.66 \\ \hline
                    100 & 0.94 \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the GMM algorithm at different heights}
                \label{tab:dimGMM}
            \end{subfloat}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

What I currently get:

[image: My current result]

I want something like this below but adding (a) and (b) subcaptions:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

It works with either `subcaption`:
[image]

or with `floatrow` (which makes it easy to have side captions):

[image]

I supposed you wanted the row of subtables to be displayed across both columns. Here's the code, which I commented for the `floatrow` version:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\thispagestyle{plain} % To force page numbering when using conference IEEEtran
\pagestyle{plain} % To force page numbering when using conference IEEEtran
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname} % For autoref to name subfloats as Figure
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}

%%%%%%%%%% FIGURES %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % Figures caption
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup{labelsep = period} % Figure 2. Caption (rather than Figure 2: Caption)
%\usepackage{float} % To place figures where I want with [H]
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} % Fig.2 (rather than Figure 2)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption, floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}%[H]
           \centering
           \captionsetup[subtable]{position = below}
          \captionsetup[table]{position=top}
           \caption{Blahblah}
           \begin{subtable}{0.3\linewidth}
               \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                   \hline
                   \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                   30 & 0.75 \\ \hline
                   50 & 1.25 \\ \hline
                   70 & 1.75 \\ \hline
                   100 & 2.50 \\ \hline
               \end{tabular}
               \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the FFT algorithm at different heights}
               \label{tab:dimFFT}
           \end{subtable}%
           \hspace*{4em}
           \begin{subtable}{0.3\linewidth}
               \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                   \hline
                   \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                   30 & 0.28 \\ \hline
                   50 & 0.47 \\ \hline
                   70 & 0.66 \\ \hline
                   100 & 0.94 \\ \hline
               \end{tabular}
                \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the GMM algorithm at different heights}
                 \label{tab:dimGMM}
           \end{subtable}
       \end{table*}
%
% \begin{table*}%[H]
%             \centering
%             \floatsetup[subtable]{capposition=beside, capbesideposition=bottom, capbesidesep=none}
%             \floatsetup[table]{capposition= top}
%             \captionsetup[subtable]{justification =justified}
%             \ttabbox[\FBwidth]
%             {\begin{subfloatrow}
%                 \ttabbox[1.25\FBwidth]{\caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the FFT algorithm at different heights}
%                 \label{tab:dimFFT1}}%
%                 {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
%                     \hline
%                     \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
%                     30 & 0.75 \\ \hline
%                     50 & 1.25 \\ \hline
%                     70 & 1.75 \\ \hline
%                     100 & 2.50 \\ \hline
%                 \end{tabular}}
%             \ttabbox[1.25\FBwidth]{ \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the GMM algorithm at different heights}
%                 \label{tab:dimGMM1}}
%                 {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
%                     \hline
%                     \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
%                     30 & 0.28 \\ \hline
%                     50 & 0.47 \\ \hline
%                     70 & 0.66 \\ \hline
%                     100 & 0.94 \\ \hline
%                 \end{tabular}}
%             \end{subfloatrow}}%
%             {\caption{Blahblah}}
%         \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, your first option is exactly what I want. However, I get this error when adding the subcaption package. I need the subfig package for some other figures I have with subfloats.

Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfig package. \endinput}{}

Comment: And you really can't do without subfig?

Comment: How then can I put my images with subfloat? It doesn't work without subfig and I don't know another way...

Comment: But why do you need subfloat? `Subcaption` also has a `subfigure`environment, you can define new subfloat types. `Floatrow` (which cooperates with `subcaption`, but has more possibilities) has its own commands too.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the font size of the `(a) caption` and `(b) caption`?