# Tabulars in the same table with separate captions

Tags: tables, captions

I'm trying to put two tables side by side and with **separate captions**. But I get only one caption (namely the last one I insert).
Here's my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \textbf{value} & \textbf{weight} & \textbf{ratio} \\
             % data ...                   
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{The first generated matrix}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \textbf{value} & \textbf{weight} & \textbf{ratio} \\
             % data ...
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{The second generated matrix}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
```

Here's the output I get:

[image]

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try subcaption in order to get rid of the minipages. If you don't want to have a global caption for both tables, you can simply deactive it.https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321359/two-tables-side-by-side-with-independent-and-global-captions

If you want to keep your code, then get rid of the float environment and use `\captionof{table}{...}`

Comment: You need to insert a `%` (comment) character immediately after the first `\end{minipage}` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `\captionof` command provided by the *caption* package.

**Updated** by inserting `\noindent` following  @Mico'comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \textbf{value} & \textbf{weight} & \textbf{ratio} \\
             % data ...                   
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{The first generated matrix}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \textbf{value} & \textbf{weight} & \textbf{ratio} \\
             % data ...
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{The second generated matrix}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You  should insert a `\noindent` directive immediately before the first `\begin{minipage}` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place a `%` character (comment character) immediately after the first `\end{minipage}` directive.

Also, don't use `center` environments inside `minipage` environments. Instead, use `\centering` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose suitable page parameters
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|lll|}
    \hline
    \textbf{value} & \textbf{weight} & \textbf{ratio} \\
    % data ...                   
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The first generated matrix}
    \end{minipage}% <--- new
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|lll|}
    \hline
    \textbf{value} & \textbf{weight} & \textbf{ratio} \\
    % data ...                   
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The second generated matrix}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```